# How to get the first revision without having a delete button?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svn, ng-switch

```
<div class="right modal-footer">
        <a class="modal-action waves-effect btn-flat left" ng-switch-when="true" ng-click="delete()">Delete</a>
        <a class="modal-action waves-effect btn-flat" ng-click="close()">Cancel</a>
        <a class="modal-action waves-effect btn-flat" ng-click="save()">Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

The first revision or revision A should not have a delete button. Every other revision needs to have one, so that's revision B, C, etc. Does anyone have any ideas on how i can do this?

The above part is the footer for the summary revision dialog. It includes the action buttons of save, cancel, and delete. Delete button is the main focus here.

The below part is the JavaScript controller code that tells what the button to do. When the revision is opened it will display the original revisions details along with which revision this is. the close function is simple, just simply closing the dialog without saving the entered and changed information. The save function is also pretty simple, saves the entered data and will show the changes when the save button is clicked on. The Delete function will delete the current revision and move back the the revision before it, so for example, deleting revision C will display revision B. But what I am trying to do is hide the delete button on Revision A(the first revision) so it will not delete the initial revision and keep the delete button display for any other revision.

Thank you developers for your help.

```
angular.module('Comet').controller('RevisionEditController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $objectExtensions, $odataModel, $validation, $toast, ProposalsService, ErrorsService) {
const DIALOG_SEL = '#revisionEditDialog';
$scope.originalRevision = null;
$scope.revision = null;


/**
 * Opens the dialog.
 * @param {number} proposal - The proposal that the revision is for.
 * @param {object} [revision] - The existing revision to edit. Null when creating a new revision.
 */
$scope.open = function (proposal, revision) {
    $scope.originalRevision = new $odataModel.ProposalDetail(revision);
    $scope.revision = new $odataModel.ProposalDetail(revision);
    $scope.revision.rev = revision ? revision.rev : getNextRevision(proposal.proposalDetails);
    $scope.revision.proposal = {
        id: proposal.id
    };

    $(DIALOG_SEL).modal('open');
};


/**
 * Closes the dialog.
 */
$scope.close = function () {
    $(DIALOG_SEL).modal('close');
};


/**
 * Saves the revision.
 */
$scope.save = function () {
    if ($validation.validate($scope.revisionEditForm)) {
        $rootScope.dataReady = false;

        if ($scope.revision.id) {
            ProposalsService.editProposalDetail($scope.revision.proposal.id, $scope.revision.id, $scope.originalRevision, $scope.revision)
                .then(onSaveSuccess, onSaveFailure);
        } else {
            ProposalsService.addProposalDetail($scope.revision.proposal.id, $scope.revision)
                .then(onSaveSuccess, onSaveFailure);
        }
    }
};


/**
 * Deletes the revision.
 */
$scope.delete = function () {
    ProposalsService.deleteProposalDetail($scope.revision.proposal.id, $scope.revision.id)
        .then(onDeleteSuccess, onDeleteFailure);
};


/**
 * Calls the revision updated callback and closes the dialog.
 * @param {object} updatedRevision - The updated revision.
 */
function onSaveSuccess(updatedRevision) {
    $scope.$ctrl.onRevisionUpdated({ revision: updatedRevision });
    $scope.close();
    $rootScope.dataReady = true;
}


/**
 * Displays an error message and logs the exception.
 * @param {object} ex - The exception to log.
 */
function onSaveFailure(ex) {
    $toast.error('There was an error saving the revision. Please try again.');
    ErrorsService.log(ex);
    $rootScope.dataReady = true;
}


/**
 * Calls the revision deleted callback and closes the dialog.
 * @param {number} id - The ID of the revision that was deleted.
 */
function onDeleteSuccess(id) {
    $scope.$ctrl.onRevisionDeleted({ id: id });
    $scope.close();
    $rootScope.dataReady = true;
}


/**
 * Displays an error message and logs the exception.
 * @param {object} ex - The exception to log.
 */
function onDeleteFailure(ex) {
    $toast.error('There was an error deleting the revision. Please try again.');
    ErrorsService.log(ex);
    $rootScope.dataReady = true;
}


/**
 * Gets the next revision number.
 * @param {object[]} revisions - The previous revisions.
 * @returns {string} The next revision number.
 */
function getNextRevision(revisions) {
    var nextRevision = '';
    var latestRevision = revisions
        .sort(function (a, b) {
            var order = 0;

            if (a.id > b.id)
                order = -1;
            else if (a.id < b.id)
                order = 1;

            return order;
        })[0];

    if (latestRevision) {
        nextRevision = latestRevision.rev ? '' : 'A';
        var increment = true;

        for (var idx = latestRevision.rev.length - 1; idx >= 0 && increment; idx--) {
            var currLetter = latestRevision.rev[idx].charCodeAt(0);

            if (currLetter == 90) {
                nextRevision = nextRevision + 'A';
            } else {
                increment = false;
                nextRevision = String.fromCharCode(currLetter + 1) + nextRevision;
            }
        }

        if (nextRevision.length < latestRevision.rev.length) {
            nextRevision = latestRevision.substring(0, nextRevision.length - 1) + nextRevision;
        }
    }

    return nextRevision;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a loop where you iterate the revisions, use the loop's index to check with ngIf if the button should be shown.